# How to remove catalog name from url?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.7

I have PrestaShop 1.7.8.7

My application is located in /public_html/home.
I assigned domain to catalog /home, but to access my website I need to use url domain.com/home/ to access homepage.
How do I make it just domain.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to move your Prestashop installation files from the **/public_html/home** directory and  put it everything in **/public_html** directory.

Then you'll have to change the "physical_uri" value in **ps_shop_url** database table from **/home/** to **/**

You can either do this directly from DB or from Backoffice in the "Seo&Url" section.

Make sure to save your settings afterwards so a new **.htaccess** file will be regenerated in the web folder root with correct paths.